# Django ajax listview editing objects one by one

Tags: django, ajax

Hi I have a django project where im rendering a listview with ajax and i wana update one object in this list view with a modal and ajax. I am struggling to understand because i think im not familiar enough with ajax and webdevelopment.

What i want to be beable to do is basically edit any of those single objects being rendered with a modal form. i get some random objects data when i click edit button.

I am not sure what other information i can provide but please let me know if more clarity needed.